# How can I set the level of precision of a value obtained through static casting?

Tags: c++

I want to set the precision to max 2 or three for the variable `correctAnswer`. I dont want to format the output but store in the memory with max 3 precision. Both `a` and `b` are integer values.

```
double correctAnswer = static_cast<double>(a) / b;
```

Comment: Two or three *what* ?

Comment: You can't set it through a cast. And double can't represent all values so it can't hold just 2 or 3 decimal places anyways.

Comment: You can't.  You control the precision when you output it with proper formatting.

Comment: @Quentin My best _guess_ would be - decimal places.

Comment: Unwise to cripple values, always work to maximum precision, then if required restrict the output. Anyway `double` has no concept of decimal places.

Comment: Is this for a money calculation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about as clear as mud. Please refine the question as the comments suggest you should.

Comment: Do note that if this is supposed to represent money then you should not be using a floating point type to begin with.

Comment: I doubt this is proper duplicate

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok, BTW, if you see the timestamps it was quasi simultaneous...

Comment: Guys I dont want to format the output. I want to store the value in variable CorrectAnswer with max 3 precision. Actually I am trying to get double input from user and compare it with CorrectAnswer which shall be difficult for user to answer correctly if more than 3 precision are compared.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a precision for a cast. But you can for the output

```
double d = 3.14159265358979;
std::cout.precision(3);
std::cout << "Pi: " << std::fixed << d << std::endl;
```

Comment: *“NOTE: This does not round the values for you.”* Doesn’t it? Also, you’ll probably want to set `fixed`, too.

Comment: thanks. updated the post

Answer (score 1):

You can use integer arithmetic for that:

```
const int precision = 100;
double correctAnswer = precision * a / b / static_cast<double>( precision );
```

you need to make sure that `precision * a` still fits to `int` or use bigger type and when you compare/output `correctAnswer` you still need to handle `double` properly